# Two Spring Cloud Data Flow Servers Pointing to Same Database(Multi Node)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I want to deploy two SCDF servers locally by pointing it to same Database.
Suppose now Server1 starts executing Job1 and it goes down in between. How to make server2 to continue this processing.

I am deploying only batch applications into SCDF.